# multilingual ios app using xamarin

Tags: xamarin, monotouch.dialog

I am a newbie in xamarin.I want to create a iOS multilingual application in xamarin but not able to find  in reference for the same.plz provide me with the way out.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here: [Localization on Xamarin.iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20128657/localization-on-xamarin-ios)

You have to use the standard lproj to translate your application. Some of the fundamentals are covered here: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_resources/